# How to read file from another(nested) folder?

Tags: rust, file-io

This is my folder structure.

```
src
├── main.rs
└── assembly_files
    └── toyRISC.asm
```

Why is this not enough or where is the error?
I tried with raw `&str`:

```
let filename = "./assembly_files/toyRISC.asm";
let result = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("Please provide valid file name");
```

Also tried using `Path` and `OsStr` , shown in code below.

```
// main.rs
use std::{ffi::OsStr, fs, path::Path};
fn main() {
    let filename = "assembly_files/toyRISC.asm";
    let path = Path::new("./assembly_files/toyRISC.asm");
    println!("{:?}", path);

    let result = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("Please provide valid file name");
}
```

This is the error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Please provide valid file name: Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." 
}', src\main.rs:6:43
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a relative Path to a file, e.g. `Path::new("./assembly_files/toyRISC.asm");` the path is relative to the folder from which you call the executable. Note that this isn't necessarily the folder where the executable is stored!

If you simply run `cargo run` at the root of your project to run it, then you need to change the path to `Path::new("./src/assembly_files/toyRISC.asm");`